# Python Tweepy Search Returns absolutely nothing

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using recommended code from tweepy. 
Documentation says to use:

```
#override tweepy.StreamListener to add logic to on_status
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

        myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
        myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
        myStream.filter(track=['OWASP'])
```

I get an error stating that "myStreamListner" cannot be found, which is on the line of the `tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)`

I'm not sure why, because I have the "import tweepy" being used.
Is there any additional code I need such as an extra import 
or do I need to add some more authorization code? 
I have the tokens and the keys all 4 of them added. 
Any advice would be nice, because the only thing I am trying to do is search for `OWASP` using tweepy.

I have the `myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()` which defines the `myStreamListener` which I would think is correct from [tweepy's documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.6.0/streaming_how_to.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to remove all indentation from those last 3 lines. They look like they should be executed at the base level.

Comment: I tried that ,but still the code does not work. I'm confused to how it is not working. Thank you for telling me about the indentations.

Comment: I think I know why I am not seeing any search results. I think I need to print the results out ,but how should I do that? I tried to use print(myStream.filter(track=['OWASP']))  however intelisense complained and gave me an error. Any advice on how to print the results from the search? Sorry to ask you about this ,because you probably have many other things to do in the world. Life is busy. Thank you for replying Mulli. :)

Comment: The 
`def on_status(self, status): print(status.text)` code is supposed to print when it gets new tweets, so I don't know what's happening. Any other error messages?